# Doctrine 2: Save a 'date' field

Tags: php, date, doctrine-orm

I have this YAML definition entity:

```
Entity\Visit:
    type: entity
    table: visit
    fields:
        date:
            type: date
            id: true
        count:
            type: integer
            nullable: true
            options:
                unsigned: true
                default: 1

    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

And the date field is created:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="date")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
 */
private $date;
```

If I try insert a new record in this way:

```
$date = new \DateTime('now');

$visit = new \Entity\Visit();
$visit->setDate($date);
$visit->setCount(1);
$em->persist($visit);
$em->flush();
```

I have this error:

> ContextErrorException in UnitOfWork.php line 1413: Catchable Fatal
>   Error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

And I do it in this way:

```
$date = new \DateTime('now');
$date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

This error is shown:

> FatalThrowableError in DateType.php line 53: Call to a member function
>   format() on string

Can anybody help me in order to insert (or update) a 'date' field using Doctrine2? Thanks.

**UPDATE**: The field in database have to be a 'date' field.

Comment: You have used `@ORM\Column(name="date", type="date")` and you are saving \DateTime object. So first change `type=datetime`.

Comment: @jigar-pancholi But I need that field is 'date' type.

Comment: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html You chould convert from DateTime to string on prePersist for insert/update.

Comment: @ka_lin: Thanks, but if I do `$this->date = $this->date->format("Y-m-d");` on prePersist event, this error is shown **FatalThrowableError in DateType.php line 53: Call to a member function format() on string**. Can you help me more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have found the problem by myself: The problem is because of **the primary key is a date column**. It seems that Doctrine does not like those stuff.

My new YML file:

```
Entity\Visit:
    type: entity
    table: visit
    fields:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
            options:
                unsigned: true
        date:
            type: date
            unique: true
        count:
            type: integer
            nullable: true
            options:
                unsigned: true
                default: 1

    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Now, I can do this:

```
$date = new \DateTime('now');
$visit = new \Entity\Visit();
$visit->setDate($date);
$visit->setCount(1);
$em->persist($visit);
$em->flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code:

```
$date = new \DateTime();

$visit = new \Entity\Visit();
$visit->setDate($date->format('Y-m-d'));
$visit->setCount(1);
$em->persist($visit);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I wrote in the queestion, if I do that then this error is shown: **FatalThrowableError in DateType.php line 53: Call to a member function format() on string**